# Javascript: What is this? Array in array? I don't understand why I can't access it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Good morning,

I get data from JSON, with physical addresses that get converted to geo coordinates (If needed I can put the whole code here or a link to the site under construction).

Then I need to work with these coordinates to calculate distances or whatever.
But somehow I can't access them.

my code (extract) looks like this:

```
var positionsCenter = [];

for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        lux.geocode({
            num: positions[i].num,
            street: positions[i].street,
            zip: positions[i].zip,
            locality: positions[i].locality
        }, function (position) {
            **positionsCenter[i] = position;**
            var pFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(position, 'EPSG:2169', 'EPSG:3857')),
                id: i
            });
            vectorSource.addFeature(pFeature);
        });
    }
```

These are coordinates on a map (vector layer) but something's wrong.
When I output this via:

```
console.log(positionsCenter);
```

It gives me this:

```
[]
0: (2) [75980.11870000046, 75098.00039954418]
1: (2) [87897.10419999996, 63546.633999540085]
2: (2) [88238.34310000022, 63389.17289954127]
3: (2) [73701.38559999966, 76385.07059954498]
4: (2) [71212.77219999957, 74969.26619954518]
5: (2) [80450.28039999957, 72414.96529954427]
6: (2) [83811.06230000037, 75487.27249954658]
7: (2) [86081.38100000011, 86362.58049954918]
8: (2) [77022.02340000033, 80667.17809954635]
9: (2) [66163.39429999988, 62664.86699954068]
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But when I try to access one of the entries like this:

```
console.log(positionsCenter[1]);
```

or

```
console.log(positionsCenter[1][1]);
```

or even

```
console.log(positionsCenter.length);
```

it's always undefined!

What do I miss? I'm confused :-/

Thank you for any help.
Best regards,
Claude

Here's the whole part of this code:

```
var map;
var vectorSource;
var highlightedFeature = null;
var selectedFeature = null;

function loadMap() {

    map = new lux.Map({
        target: 'map',
        bgLayer: 'basemap_2015_global', //default basemap_2015_global, streets_jpeg
        zoom: 16, //18
        position: [75977, 75099],
        showLayerInfoPopup: true,
        search: {
            target: 'searchbox',
            dataSets: ['Adresse', 'Coordinates']
        }
    });

    //-------------------------------------------------------------- FEATURES -
    vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: []
    });
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    });

    function styleFunction(feature, resolution) {
        var sti = feature.get('status');
        const liv = 'livraison';
        const tak = 'take-away';
        var newColor = [128, 128, 128];
        if (sti.includes('ouvert')) {
            newColor = [0, 255, 0];
        }

        var imgSource = '../images/pin.png';

        if (sti.includes(liv) && sti.includes(tak)) {
            imgSource = '../images/pin-livraison-takeaway.png';
        } else {
            if (sti.includes(liv)) {
                imgSource = '../images/pin-livraison.png';
            } else {
                if (sti.includes(tak)) {
                    imgSource = '../images/pin-takeaway.png';
                }
            }
        }
        var isSelected = feature.get('selected') || feature.get('highlighted');
        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                color: newColor,
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                src: imgSource,
                scale: isSelected ? 1.5 : 1
            }))
        });
        return [iconStyle];
    }

    vectorLayer.setStyle(styleFunction);
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

    for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        lux.geocode({
            num: positions[i].num,
            street: positions[i].street,
            zip: positions[i].zip,
            locality: positions[i].locality
        }, function (position) {
            positionsCenter[i] = position;
            var pFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(position, 'EPSG:2169', 'EPSG:3857')),
                id: i
            });

            const sti = statuses[i];
            pFeature.set('status', sti);
            pFeature.setId(i);
            pFeature.set('selected', false);
            pFeature.set('highlighted', false);
            vectorSource.addFeature(pFeature);
        });

        //console.log(positions[i]);
    }

    map.on('click', function (evt) {
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
            return feature;
        });
        if (feature !== undefined) {
            if (selectedFeature !== null) {
                selectedFeature.set('selected', false);
                selectedFeature = null;
            }
            feature.set('selected', true);
            selectedFeature = feature;
            var outPut = feature.get('id');
            infoField.innerHTML = arr[outPut].innerHTML;
            infoField.style.display = 'block';
            CloseinfoField.style.display = 'block';
            galImage.style.display = 'none';
            ClosegalImage.style.display = 'none';
            getThumbs(outPut);

            for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[j].classList.remove('active');
            }
            arr[outPut].className += ' active';
            var current = document.getElementById('item' + outPut);
            current.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'center'
            });
        } else {
            console.log('');
        }
    });
    map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
        if (highlightedFeature !== null) {
            highlightedFeature.set('highlighted', false);
            highlightedFeature = null;
        }
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
            return feature;
        });
        if (feature !== undefined) {
            highlightedFeature = feature;
            highlightedFeature.set('highlighted', true);
        }
    });


    //------------------------------------------------------------------ DISTANCE -
    var sourceProj = map.getView().getProjection();

    var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
    var coordinates1 = [75977, 75099];
    var coordinates2 = [76977, 75099];

    // EDIT/UPDATE ----------------------------------------

function delay(ms) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve();
            }, ms);
        });
    }

    function getFive() {
        return delay(100).then(function () {
            return positionsCenter[0];
        })
    }
    getFive().then(function (five) {
        console.log(five);
    });
    // EDIT ----------------------------------------

    
    var c1 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates1, sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326');
    var c2 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates2, sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326');

    var distance = wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(c1, c2);
    console.log(distance);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------- /DISTANCE -

    document.getElementById('myLocation').addEventListener('click', getLocation);
    document.getElementById('navList').addEventListener('click', getnavList);
}
```

Comment: Here's the link to the site if needed: https://www.wim.lu/d915dbce-2c66-11eb-8cff-277212969116/4.0/

Comment: Are you trying to access the array elements outside of the callback to `geocode`?

Comment: @maazadeeb No, that was my first idea too

Comment: Where exactly *are* you trying to access it?

Comment: @deceze I have updated the question, please have a look at it again. I'm lost

Comment: You *are* trying to access the async result before it’s available. Read the two linked duplicates.

Comment: I have read the 2 linked posts but I don't know how to solve it for me :-(

Comment: Got it :-) How do I get both values from one array? This only gives me the first one. I tried [0][0] too but that's undefined again...

Comment: Nevermind. All is working now as expected :-)
Thank you all for your help.